# Android: GridView shows duplicate images upon scrolling

Tags: android, performance, gridview

Basically, I have stored thumbnail file names in the database and all the thumbnails in a folder called 'KinderThumbnails'.

Ideally, the GridView should display all the thumbnails and selecting a thumbnail should open a form where data related to that image is retrieved from the database and displayed.

However, some images make duplicate entries upon scrolling and when clicked upon, show empty form.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (row != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    } else {
        //inflate row and assign to holder

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_main, viewGroup, false);
        holder.cardImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.cardActivity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cardActivity);
        holder.cardDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cardDate);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }

    //get each object from the Card Class and set parameters
    Card temp = list.get(i);
    File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/KinderThumbnails/" + temp.imageFileName);

    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imgFile.getAbsolutePath())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.img_not_found)
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.cardImage);

        holder.cardDate.setText(temp.date);
        holder.cardActivity.setText(temp.activityName);

    }
    return row;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition statement `if (imgFile.exists())` only trigger if the image exists, this makes the **recycled** list item views unchanged, so the drawable on the ImageView is not changed

You need to set the `holder.cardImage`'s drawable if the image didn't exist

```
if (imgFile.exists()) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(imgFile.getAbsolutePath())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.img_not_found)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.cardImage);

    holder.cardDate.setText(temp.date);
    holder.cardActivity.setText(temp.activityName);

} else {
    holder.cardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_not_found);
    holder.cardDate.setText("");
    holder.cardActivity.setText("");
}
```

Comment: You can approve my answer if that helped you :)